# Symfony2 add field to form dynamically when onChange occurs

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm starting to investigate Symfony2 framework and it seems that I've messed up some things in my mind.

I am trying to do a relatively simple thing; Dynamically add an extra field to a form depending on the value of a select box. Let's assume for simplicity that I don't have my form attached to any entity, so what I eventually want to get back is an array of values.

So, as a simple example I would have this controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, array('allow_extra_fields' => true))
    ->add('test', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType')
    ->add('select', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType', array(
      'choices' => array(
        'Maybe' => null,
        'Yes' => true,
        'No' => false,
      ),
      'choices_as_values' => true,
    ))
    ->add('submit', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType')
    ->getForm();

  $form->handleRequest($request);
  if ($form->isValid()) {
    dump($form->getData());
    die;
  }
  return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
  ));
}

/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 */
public function AddFieldAction(Request $request)
{
  return new JsonResponse($request->get('form'));

}
```

And the javascript of the view could be:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#form_select').change(function(){
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var value = $(this).val();
        var data = {};
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = value;

        $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url("test") }}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {        
               console.log(response);
                   if (response.select == 1) {
                       $('#form').append("<label> extra field </label> <input type='text' id='extra_field' name="form[extra_field]"></input>");
               }               
           }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
              });
    })
})
```

Now this would return the field correctly, as this would invoke the `AddFieldAction` and it would add the appropriate HTML in the form. When i would try to submit the form, in the `$form->isValid` part, I could get all the submitted data with the `$form->getData()` and `$form->getExtraData()` methods.

Question is, is this the optimal way to do it? Should (and could) I use Form Events instead? I was trying to use form events but it becomes a mess and I get lost easily in the hierarchy of `PRE_SUBMIT` or `PRE_SET_DATA` conficting each other.

Comment: If it works and you don't mind the javascript then go with it.  I'm a little surprised that isValid() allows the extra field but again if it works then fine.  And yes, this is one of several seemingly simple things for which the form component requires events and a somewhat byzantine approach.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, the trick of allowing the extra field is the param in the constructor of FormBuilder `createFormBuilder(null, array('allow_extra_fields' => true))`. Without this, it complains about "extra fields not allowed".

Regarding events, unfortunately I couldn't make it work.

Comment: I think you're right to be considering FormEvents!

Comment: @CameronHurd, FormEvents was my first attempt. Unfortunately, all the examples (even in the official documentation) are describing modification of an existing HTML element's values and not how to add or remove elements.I can't seem to wrap my head around the series of events to achieve this. Seems to me `PRE_SET_DATA` and `POST_SUBMIT` or `PRE_SUBMIT` have to be nicely and cleverly combined to achieve this, but..stuck there.